# C# linq using null or empty strings in a where statment

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a stored procedure in my DB that allows me to send nulls as parameters. If the value is null then it's used in the where statement. However, I don't need to query the database a second time because I have the data in a binding list.

I have been trying to figure out a way to accomplish the same task in a Linq statement. Below is the Linq code I have now. Sometimes the jobname or jobnumber could be empty. Is there any way to include an operator to say `if not empty, use it` in the `where` clause?  So far the only way I got it to work is to have  a deep `if/else` statement. I was looking around and it looks like the only way to do this is with a lambda expression and not a Linq? But I have no idea on how to accomplish that with a binding list?

```
  t = new BindingList<Tracking>(
                                 OmanWorkflow.TrackingData.Where(o => o.Created >= dateFrom.Value
                                 && o.Created <= dateTo.Value
                                 && o.JobNumber.Contains(txtFilterJobNumber.Text)
                                 && o.JobName.Contains(txtFilterJobName.Text)

                                 ).ToList());
```

Comment: Rather than a single `Where` clause with `&&` in it, use multiple `Where` clauses. `var query = OmanWorkflow.TrackingData.Where(o => o.Created >= dateFrom.Value
                                 && o.Created <= dateTo.Value); if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilterJobNumber.Text)) { query = query.Where(z => o.JobNumber.Contains(txtFilterJobNumber.Text)) }` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends which flavor of Linq you are using. If it is Linq To SQL then simply:

```
var t = new BindingList<Tracking>(
         OmanWorkflow.TrackingData.Where(o => o.Created >= dateFrom.Value
         && o.Created <= dateTo.Value
         && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilterJobNumber.Text) ||
             o.JobNumber.Contains(txtFilterJobNumber.Text))
         && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilterJobName.Text) ||
             o.JobName.Contains(txtFilterJobName.Text))).ToList());
```

Linq To SQL is clever enough to check if txtFilterJobNumber\Name is empty\null and if it is then doesn't even include it in the where clause generated.

With EF however, the story is a little different and using if ... construct is perfectly fine and easy:

```
var td = OmanWorkflow.TrackingData.Where(o => 
            o.Created >= dateFrom.Value && o.Created <= dateTo.Value);

// this likely should be o.Created < dateTo.Value
//

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilterJobNumber.Text))
{
   td = td.Where(o.JobNumber.Contains(txtFilterJobNumber.Text));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilterJobName.Text))
{
   td = td.Where(o.JobName.Contains(txtFilterJobName.Text));
}
var t = new BindingList<Tracking>(td).ToList());
```

Comment: Good answer. Just to add that EF Core is also clever enough to eliminate the constant `true` expression. The second approach though works well for any LINQ implementation, being it `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` and clever or not clever enough.

Answer (score 1):

By combining a IsNullOrEmpty chack with the actual clause:

```
 t = new BindingList<Tracking>(
                             OmanWorkflow.TrackingData.Where(o => o.Created >= dateFrom.Value
                             && o.Created <= dateTo.Value
                             && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilterJobNumber.Text) || o.JobNumber.Contains(txtFilterJobNumber.Text))
                             && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilterJobName.Text) || o.JobName.Contains(txtFilterJobName.Text))

                             ).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid having to write out the conditions by using the null propagation and null coalescing operators:

```
OmanWorkflow.TrackingData.Where(o => o.Created >= dateFrom.Value
                             && o.Created <= dateTo.Value
                             && (o.JobNumber?.Contains(txtFilterJobNumber.Text) ?? true)
                             && (o.JobName?.Contains(txtFilterJobName.Text) ?? true)
).ToList());
```

If `o.JobNumber` is null, then that part of the clause is effectively skipped (made true). Likewise for `o.JobName`.

Comment: Looks concise, but won't work if `TrackingData` is `IQueryable<T>` (`?.` operator is not supported in expression trees).